# How to convert uint8 to single? MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an array with `384x255 uint8` contains the features of an image, I want to train this image by using `svmtrain`. How to convert this array to *`1-by-N single`* matrix so the number of rows will be equal to `label`.

---

I will explain my problem, I have extracted `HOG` features for ~500 images and saved results in a matrix.. easily, this matrix consist of 500 rows, each row has a `HOG` feature of one image.
**BUT** when I tried to extract `LBP` feature every thing is different. The matrix is about  `384x255 uint8` for each image (I have ~500 images). I make reshape for this big matrix to be 500 rows, each raw has `LBP` features of an image but after classification them by `SVM` classifier, the results was terrible. So, does reshaping and converting from `uint8` to `single` may change data and effect results?

Comment: How can you have a `1 x N` matrix if you want the number of rows to be equal to `label`?  There is only **one** row in a `1 x N` matrix.

Comment: Thank you for you question. "label = 1 row" but my matrix = 384x255. I need to make the number of rows in 'label' and matrix equal. @rayryeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your array is stored in `A`:

```
B = reshape(single(A), 1, []);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @rayryeng. your answer so helpful.
does reshaping matrix effect on it's data? I mean, in my matrix I have LBP features of an image, after reshaping it, does stored data change or not?

Comment: It changes precision to single. What do you mean by the data changing?

Comment: I will explain my problem, I have extracted HOG features for ~500 images and saved results in a matrix.. easily, this matrix consist of 500 rows each row has a HOG feature of one image.
BUT when I tried to extract LBP feature every thing is different. The matrix is about  384x255 uint8 for each image (I have ~500 images). I make reshape for this big matrix to be 500 rows, each raw has LBP features of an image but after classification them by SVM classifier, the results was terrible. So, does reshaping and changing from uint8 to single may change data and effect results? @rayryeng